# 2 SQL Searches off of one id in a CodeIgniter MCV enviornment

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know my problem is where I call the variables in the Controller $name and $year, I'm not sure how to format that array to a variable in the Controller.

Model:

```
function getId($id)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('HWC');

    return $result->result();
}

function getVariations($name, $year)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where(array('ModelName' => $name, 'Year' => $year));
    $variations = $this->db->get('HWC');

    if(mysql_num_rows($variations) != 0)
    {
        return $variations->result();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('testingsearch');
$data['records'] = $this->testingsearch->getId($id);

$name = $records->ModelName;
$year = $records->Year;

$data['variations'] = $this->testingsearch->getVariations($name, $year);
```

View:

```
 foreach($variations as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['color'];
    echo $row['Tampo'];
 }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I can not for the life of me get the page to display. The page has a variable in the url that is loaded. What I'm trying to find is entries in the database that have the exact ModelName and Year as the entry that I'm on.

Comment: I currently get HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. with the setup I have above

Answer (score 0):

```
function getId($id)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('HWC');
    return $result->result();
}

You are returning object with result() but displaying as array

foreach($variations as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['color'];
    echo $row['Tampo'];
}
```

Change it like this

```
return $result->result_array();
```

Now view will work fine. And in controller you are making mistake here

```
$data['records'] = $this->testingsearch->getId($id);
```

Change it to

```
$records    =   $this->testingsearch->getId($id);
```

And now these instructions should work fine but with a condition

```
if($records){
    $name = $records->ModelName;
    $year = $records->Year;

    $data['variations'] = $this->testingsearch->getVariations($name, $year);
}
```

Comment: I need it to stay $data['records'] (it's been working this way, because I pass $data along with a lot of other variables through to the view

Comment: but you are accessing it in the wrong way in controller. Use `$name = $data['record']->ModelName`

Comment: Actually it appears with a print_r($name) in the model, it is not actually getting passed with       `$name = $data['records']->ModelName;`